# Using Application context everywhere?

Tags: android, android-context

In an Android app, is there anything wrong with the following approach:

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {

    private static MyApp instance;

    public MyApp() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

and pass it everywhere (e.g. SQLiteOpenHelper) where context is required (and not leaking of course)?

Comment: Just to elaborate for others implementing this, you can then modify the `<application>` node of your AndroidManifest.xml file to include the following attribute definition: `android:name="MyApp"`.  MyApp needs to be under the same package that your manifest references.

Comment: Why the static? The application instance is *always* created before anything else. Wherever you are expected to access the application context, it will be passed to you as arguments. This approach may complicate your tests. Static-itis promotes common coupling.

Comment: Just so you know you're returning your application by one of its super interfaces, so if you provided additional methods within MyApp you would not be able to use them. Your getContext() should instead have a return type of MyApp, and that way you can use methods added later, as well as all the methods in ContextWrapper and Context.

Comment: See also http://goo.gl/uKcFn - it's another reply related to similar post. Better set the static variable in onCreate and not c'tor.

Comment: This won't work if your SQLiteOpenHelper is used by a Content Provider, because the Content Provider's onCreate() is called before the Application's onCreate().

Comment: @MattHuggins If my package name is com.example.xyz so under application node can i define it like this android:name="com.example.xyz.MyApp" or just android:name="MyApp".

Comment: @yanchenko: Have you tested the scenario where the GC kills your app? Would your solution still work then? The reason I ask is because there are scenarios in Android where an application may ask for a `Context` to do certain tasks. For example, listening for volume changes initiated by the hardware volume keys. I suppose, in this instance, if the app has already been killed by the GC, then there won't be any `Context` available to use is there? The only solution, then, would be to check for null `Context` and respond appropriately.

Comment: @ChuongPham If the framework has killed your app, there won't be anything accessing the null context...

Comment: I think you want to call `super()` from your constructor.

Comment: FWIW, for anyone using `Xamarin` Android, this is built in as `global::Android.App.Application.Context`.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

There are a couple of potential problems with this approach, though in a lot of circumstances (such as your example) it will work well.

In particular you should be careful when dealing with anything that deals with the **`GUI`** that requires a **`Context`**. For example, if you pass the application Context into the **`LayoutInflater`** you will get an Exception. Generally speaking, your approach is excellent: it's good practice to use an **`Activity's` `Context`** within that **`Activity`**, and the **`Application Context`** when passing a context beyond the scope of an **`Activity`** to [avoid memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Also, as an **alternative** to your pattern you can use the shortcut of calling `getApplicationContext()` on a **`Context`** object (such as an Activity) to get the Application Context.

Comment: Thanks for an inspiring answer. I think I'll use this approach solely for the persistence layer (as I don't want to go with content providers). Wondering what was the motivation behind designing SQLiteOpenHelper in a way that expects a Context to be supplied instead of acquiring it from Application itself.
P.S. And your book is great!

Comment: Using the application context with `LayoutInflator` just worked for me. Must have been changed in the last three years.

Comment: Are there problems with this approach?  Or, is this exact code good for use throughout the app?

Comment: @JacobPhillips Using LayoutInflator without an activity context will miss out on that Activity's styling. So it would work in one sense, but not another.

Comment: @MarkCarter Do you mean using the Application Context will miss out on the Activity's styling?

Comment: @JacobPhillips yes, the Application Context cannot have the styling because every Activity may be styled in a different way.

Comment: Why does pass the application Context into the `LayoutInflater` cause  an Exception?

Answer (score 31):

In my experience this approach shouldn't be necessary.  If you need the context for anything you can usually get it via a call to [View.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) and using the `Context` obtained there you can call [Context.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) to get the `Application` context.  If you are trying to get the `Application` context this from an `Activity` you can always call [Activity.getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()) which should be able to be passed as the `Context` needed for a call to `SQLiteOpenHelper()`.

Overall there doesn't seem to be a problem with your approach for this situation, but when dealing with `Context` just make sure you are not leaking memory anywhere as described on the official [Google Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Answer (score 14):

Some people have asked: ***how can the singleton return a null pointer?***
I'm answering that question. (I cannot answer in a comment because I need to post code.)

It may return null in between two events: (1) the class is loaded, and (2) the object of this class is created. Here's an example:

```
class X {
    static X xinstance;
    static Y yinstance = Y.yinstance;
    X() {xinstance=this;}
}
class Y {
    static X xinstance = X.xinstance;
    static Y yinstance;
    Y() {yinstance=this;}
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
    X x = new X();
    Y y = new Y();
    System.out.println("x:"+X.xinstance+" y:"+Y.yinstance);
    System.out.println("x:"+Y.xinstance+" y:"+X.yinstance);
    }
}
```

Let's run the code:

```
$ javac A.java 
$ java A
x:X@a63599 y:Y@9036e
x:null y:null
```

The second line shows that *Y.xinstance* and *X.yinstance* are *null*; they are null because the variables *X.xinstance* ans *Y.yinstance* were read when they were null.

Can this be fixed? Yes,

```
class X {
    static Y y = Y.getInstance();
    static X theinstance;
    static X getInstance() {if(theinstance==null) {theinstance = new X();} return theinstance;}
}
class Y {
    static X x = X.getInstance();
    static Y theinstance;
    static Y getInstance() {if(theinstance==null) {theinstance = new Y();} return theinstance;}
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
    System.out.println("x:"+X.getInstance()+" y:"+Y.getInstance());
    System.out.println("x:"+Y.x+" y:"+X.y);
    }
}
```

and this code shows no anomaly:

```
$ javac A.java 
$ java A
x:X@1c059f6 y:Y@152506e
x:X@1c059f6 y:Y@152506e
```

**BUT** this is not an option for the Android `Application` object: the programmer does not control the time when it is created.

Once again: the difference between the first example and the second one is that the second example creates an instance if the static pointer is null. But a programmer cannot create *the* Android application object before the system decides to do it.

**UPDATE**

One more puzzling example where initialized static fields happen to be `null`.

*Main.java*:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,SECOND;
    private static String prefix="<", suffix=">";
    String myName;
    MyEnum() {
        myName = makeMyName();
    }
    String makeMyName() {
        return prefix + name() + suffix;
    }
    String getMyName() {
        return myName;
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("first: "+MyEnum.FIRST+" second: "+MyEnum.SECOND);
        System.out.println("first: "+MyEnum.FIRST.makeMyName()+" second: "+MyEnum.SECOND.makeMyName());
        System.out.println("first: "+MyEnum.FIRST.getMyName()+" second: "+MyEnum.SECOND.getMyName());
    }
}
```

And you get:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
first: FIRST second: SECOND
first: <FIRST> second: <SECOND>
first: nullFIRSTnull second: nullSECONDnull
```

Note that you cannot move the static variable declaration one line upper, the code will not compile.

Comment: Useful example; its good to know that there is such a hole. What I take away from this is that one should avoid referring to such a static variable during static initialization of any class.

Answer (score 11):

Application Class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

}
```

Declare the Application in the AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
/>
```

Usage:

```
MyApplication.getAppContext()
```

Comment: Prone to memory leaks. You shouldn't ever do this.

Comment: @Dragas, no it is not prone to leaks. You can do that any time.

Comment: @Dragas getApplicationContext() is actually previously leaked, so using this example won't be a problem.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to create a wrapper to get Application Context and there is a possibility that it might return "`null`" pointer.

As per my understanding, I guess its better approach to call- any of the 2
`Context.getApplicationContext()`  or `Activity.getApplication()`.

Comment: when should it return null?

Comment: There's no static Context.getApplicationContext() method that I'm aware of.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I also implement the same approach in my application, but when calling in SQLiteOpenHelper, it returns the null pointer. Any answer for this kind of situation.

Comment: This may be the case if you call SQLiteOpenHelper in a contentprovider which is loaded before the app.

Answer (score 5):

It is a good approach. I use it myself as well. I would only suggest to override `onCreate` to set the singleton instead of using a constructor.

And since you mentioned `SQLiteOpenHelper`: In `onCreate ()` you can open the database as well.

Personally I think the documentation got it wrong in saying that *There is normally no need to subclass Application*. I think the opposite is true: You should always subclass Application.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Application Context to get a System Service in the constructor. This eases testing & benefits from composition

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public MyActivity() {
       this(MyApp.getContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
    }

    public MyActivity(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
       this.notificationManager = notificationManager;
    }

    // onCreate etc

}
```

Test class would then use the overloaded constructor.

Android would use the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I like it, but I would suggest a singleton instead:

```
package com.mobidrone;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class ApplicationContext extends Application
{
    private static ApplicationContext instance = null;

    private ApplicationContext()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getInstance()
    {
        if (null == instance)
        {
            instance = new ApplicationContext();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Extending android.app.application already guarantees singleton so this is unnecessary

Comment: What if you want acess from non activity classes?

Comment: You should never `new` the Application yourself (with the possible exception of unit testing). The operating system will do that. You should also not have an constructor. That is what `onCreate` is for.

Comment: @Vincent: can you post some link on this ? preferably code - I am asking here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365797/androids-basic-components-class-loading-java-objects-lifecycle

Comment: @radzio why we shouldn't do it in constructor?

Comment: @Martin in Java, there's no way to have no constructor in a class. If there are no explicit constructors, javac generates a publuc no-arg one.

Comment: Well that's what I said: Don't declare an explicit constructor use onCreate itself because at onCreate the class usable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same approach, I suggest to write the singleton a little better:

```
public static MyApp getInstance() {

    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (MyApp.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyApp ();
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

but I'm not using everywhere, I use `getContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` where I can do it!

Comment: So, please write a comment to explain why you've downvoted the answer so I can understand. The singleton approach is widely used to get a valid context outside activities or views body...

Comment: No need as the operating system ensures that the Application is instantiated exactly once. If any I would suggest to set the Singelton in onCreate ().

Comment: A good thread-safe way to lazy initialize a singleton, but not neccessary here.

Comment: Wow, just when I thought people had finally stopped using double-checked locking... http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question was posted 13 years ago, and this is the Kotlin version of getting context everywhere.

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private var instance: MyApplication? = null

        @JvmStatic
        public final fun getContext(): Context? {
            return instance
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        instance = this
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```