# android synchronized sql database access

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization, flurry

What are some of the design options for the synchronizing the read/write of a sqlite database in an android app - something like what Google Analytics/Flurry libraries might be doing internally. They keep collecting data and send it to servers at the same time.

The app i am making collects data during app usage - and keep saving the data in a SQLite Database - and send this information to the backend - as and when the connection is available.

My question is how to design the SQLite DB access for the scenario when I might be writing to the app - while the app is sending data to the server. These events could happen at the same instance quite a number of times. I am not sure how do Google Analytics/Flurry work.

SyncAdapter / Content Provider / Plain SQLIte ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Singleton design pattern for SQLiteDatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate which actually has a very simple answer: [android can single instance of SQLiteDatabase manage synchronization between multiple threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674182/android-can-single-instance-of-sqlitedatabase-manage-synchronization-between-mul?rq=1)

You can follow the `SQLiteOpenHelper` pattern, which you can learn more about in this very very thorough article and blog post.

[Using Singleton design pattern for SQLiteDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: I guess he already was using the same instance and he was talking about accessing this instance from different threads. Singleton has nothing to do with that... I don't understand why you mentioned it here