# Multi threading and Synchronization in room database

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, android-room

I am working on an app in which multiple threads can update the same database, I am unsure about how some cases wherein two threads are trying to update the same database. I search about how the room works and explored transactions as well, but it is of no use to me in this case, I am doing the same operation but from multiple threads. how should I keep the database consistent without corrupting the data?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should use Java synchronized method to safely write and read from the DB with multiple threads (no relation to Room library as far as I know).
A synchronized method that multiple threads use would ensure mutual exclusive access to the db.

See more here: [to to implement a SQLite Manager for thread-safe read/write access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786206/to-to-implement-a-sqlite-manager-for-thread-safe-read-write-access)