# How can I send a notification from inside the onProviderDisabled method of a LocationListener

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, toast, locationlistener

How can I send a notification from inside the onProviderDisabled method of a LocationListener?

So far I have been using:

```
Toast.makeText(mainmenu, "GPS Location providers are disabled... blah blah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}});
```

but that entails using a static mainmenu variable stored when the mainmenu class is first instantiated - I gather doing it that is a bad idea, in case the mainmenu object gets removed from memory I guess - so I think I should be using notifications.

I guess I need to be able to have a reference to an activity to make the intent - but what activity can I refer to since my location listener stores no such reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work always, but you can call `Application.getApplicationContext()` and use that.

If your LocationListener is part of an Activity (in the form of an inner class) you can also use `this.MyActivity`.

Comment: using the call Application.getApplicationContext() gives this error in eclipse "getApplicationContext() Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper"
How  do  I get a good reference to the application?

Comment: In that case, you could implement the LocationListener as an inner class and use Activity.this to get your context.

Comment: Thats true, I opted to pass in the reference instead of using inner class since I defined my listeners inside a support  class with loads of static methods and static vars, but I bet your suggestion is much better especially for android.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own Interface.

```
public interface LocationUpdatesReveiver {
    /** onLocationChanged */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location);
}
```

Make your activity class implement that interface and pass a reference of it to your LocationListener class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationUpdatesReveiver{
...
        location = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new LocListener(MyActivity.this);
}
```

Call your activity's implemented method

```
public class LocListener implements LocationListener {

    private LocationUpdatesReveiver receiver;

    public LocListener(LocationUpdatesReveiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(null != location){
            receiver.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }
}
```

This is for onLocationUpdate but you could use the same technique for pretty much everything

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your class like:

```
public class myClass  extends android.app.Application implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private Location location;
    ...
```

Then just have the function in that class:

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disenabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: But my LocationListener is not defined inside an Activity.  What would "this" refer to?

Comment: I've edited the answer, you could extend android.app.Application then you have access to call getApplicationContext(), its a bit hacky but it works!

Comment: well that is interesting but it seems pretty over the top for such a simple thing - seems maybe even a little dangerous to make a second application object though I don't know why.  
  Instead of using a static reference I could pass around a reference to an activity or a reference to the application and then use app.getApplicationContext(), I guess using a reference to an application is somehow more safe that using a reference to an activity though again I'm not sure why.

Comment: It should be ok as long as you dont override any of the methods inherited from Application, but your right passing a reference would be much neater, though i've never done it before!

Comment: Passing a reference could be risky because that activity (or application) might be terminated. There are also risks of introducing memory leaks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere/987503#987503