# How to avoid OnCreate method execution when activity has been opened previously (Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.android, destruction

I have two activities `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`. When I am in `FirstActivty` I call the `SecondActivity` like that:

```
var secondActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
secondActivity.PutExtra("someExtra", someExtra);
StartActivity(secondActivity);
Finish();
```

In `SecondActivity` I call the `FirstActivity` in `OnBackPressed` method:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    StartActivity(typeof(FirstActivty));
    Finish();
}
```

I looked at answers regarding that question for `Android(Java)`. The answers were that in order to avoid `OnCreate` method to be executed in `FirstActivity` when the activity has been already created, I  don't have to destroy `FirstActivity` after I open `SecondActivity`, I have to remove `Finish()` after `StartActivity(secondActivity);` line. I removed it but `OnCreate` method still gets executed when I go back from `SecondActivity`. Does this solution work only in `Android(Java)` ,and if yes, what is the solution for `Xamarin.Android` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleInstance` in your `FirstActivity` attribute like this code.

```
   [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true,LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleInstance)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
           
        }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

If you do not want to execute the code in the `Oncreate` method, You can refer to this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6931246/10627299