# Using Context class constructor inside non-context class

Tags: android, android-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Way to get Context on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Not sure if the answer is correct, but this thing is stopping me from progress for days already.

I got two classes:

- public class CfmDbAdapter which consist:

  - private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
  - series of methods to service the database
- public class DataToArray extends Application

I extended Application just to have access to Context but I have to access methods from CfmDbadapter. In all my Activity classes I do it by:

```
private CfmDbAdapter db;    
db = new CfmDbAdapter(this);
db.open(); //one of the methods I need to access
```

I can't do that in my DataToArray class since it's parent is not a Context class (I gues). I can't acess methods staticly aswell, it would fck up whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these links
[Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)
[Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the db:
a) final
b) belonging to the class
Or you can declare some other variable, (static or final) and put a reference to db in it.