# Where do I find the ApplicationContext needed to initialize ORMLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm working with android and ormlite.  I have a problem to initialize a `ForeignCollection`.

I found this, to initialize it: `dao.getEmptyForeignCollection()`

But for the dao, i need the `DatabaseHelper`, and for the databasehelper i need the applicationContext, but in the entity i haven't a context. is there any other option?

And this is the Code, its an 1:n relation. Class Team:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
private Club club;
```

Class Club:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
private ForeignCollection<Team> teams;
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not about foreign collections but is about how [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) gets wired under Android.  All of this is explained in the documentation:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android

You specifically asked:

> But for the dao, i need the `DatabaseHelper`, and for the database helper i need the application `Context`, but in the entity i haven't a context. is there any other option?

Under Android, each class that extends `Activity`, `ListActivity`, `Service`, and `TabActivity` *also* is a `Context`.  You can see the class hierarchy from the [online docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

```
java.lang.Object
    ↳ android.content.Context
        ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper
            ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
                ↳ android.app.Activity
```

If you take a look at the [Android example](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples) projects available from the website you can see how typically an Android application is wired:

- Your main `Activity` extends `OrmLiteBaseActivity`

  ```
  public class HelloAndroid extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {
  ```
- The `onCreate` method in `OrmLiteBaseActivity` constructs your `DatabaseHelper` using the ORMLite `OpenHelperManager` and itself as the `Context`:

  ```
  OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
  ```
- You use the `OrmLiteBaseActivity.getHelper()` method to get access to the helper to create your DAOs so you can persist things to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the required dependencies.

If you entity needs a database helper, give it. 
If your database helper needs a context, give it.

Provide constructors to your classes that make the needed dependency compulsory :

```
public DataHelper( Context context ) {
  this.context = context;
}
```

Then, from your activity or application model, use

```
new DataHelper( this );
```

to inject the dependency.

A priori, it would be interesting for you to use an application class that will provide a general context for your database helper, more than creating a new database helper for each activity in its onCreate method.

Comment: Do you mean something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere).

Or more something like this 
'public Club(Context context, String name) {
 this.name = name;
}'

Comment: Exactly that :) Happy coding.