# Android Context object how to handle

Tags: java, android, android-context

This is not a question about Context object itself. I wonder what the best way to manage reference to it. When I create android objects like Activity, Service, etc - context already accessible everywhere.

But I have bunch of different classes for data access, various shared utilities, etc. I find myself writing every call and passing context alone. I wonder if there any good way to deal with context. Maybe static? Is that good idea to store reference in my own Application object like so?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public static Context Context;
```

This way I can access context from anywhere in application. Does it seem like a good idea?

Comment: You can do that to a certain degree, if you want to store the application context. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere), which discusses the potential problems with this approach. What you should **never** do is store an Activity context in your application object. You will leak that context and get into problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make `public static Context mContext;` as a global variable, and at the start of `onCreate()`, add `mContext = this;`.  It makes access much easier.  By making it public and static, other files can see the context of your main activity, and you won't have to pass it as a parameter to any function.  In my opinion, this is probably the best/easiest way to manage reference to it.  It also unclutters all sorts of references to `MainActivity.this`.

alextsc's comment shows a helpful link to problems that can occur from this as well.

Comment: or should create static getter.

Comment: I already subclass Application anyway. My app uses services, receivers, etc. Activity is just part of app. I think it would be better to expose MyApplication as static - seems like this context (Application itself) works good everywhere I needed context.

Comment: That's a memory leak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks