# Which android activity should hold objects used by other activites?

Tags: android, object, android-activity, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm wondering, where is a good place to create and hold objects in android activities? Always the activity highest in the hierarchy? Here's what I mean.

```
/* Let this be the main launcher activity */
activity1{
  List someList  // Edit: This should of course be public, my mistake.
}

/* The next activity is a child of activity1 
*  and can be started by activity 1 
*/
activity2{
  ...
  do_something(activity1.someList);  // Does this always work?
  ...
}

/* The next activity has no parent and can be launched 
*  when the app receives an intent, for example a 
*  photo is shared to my app.
*/
activityX{
  ....
  receive_intent(...);
  do_something(activity1.someList) // This might work, when app is already running
}
```

See, my problem is I'm never sure where it's okay to place objects. In my example `activity2` needs access to one of activity1's objects, which I never had any problems with. But does this case always work? Will the objects from a parent activity always stay in memory while the child activity is visible?

Can I somehow pass a reference to `someList` from `activity1` to `activity2` and pretend that `someList` has been instantiated in `activity2`? Or is this not required?

activityX on the other hand clearly will create a nullpointer exception when the app (and thus `activity1`) is not running in the background (or just not cached?).

Is there a document with guidelines for android programming covering things like this?

Comment: Doing this sort of thing may cause hard-to-debug memory leaks.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes thats my concern. So even the thing I do in activity2 is not safe to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Let's see..

> ```
> /* Let this be the main launcher activity */
> activity1{
>   List someList
> }
> ```

You might want to declare your `List` as `public` and / or `static`

---

> ```
> /* The next activity is a child of activity1 
> *  and can be started by activity 1 
> */
> activity2{
>   ...
>   do_something(activity1.someList);  // Does this always work?
>   ...
> }
> ```

This *might* work, provided a few conditions are met:

- It will only work if `activity1` is started *before* `activity2`, otherwise, `someList` will be null, as it has not been created yet.
- If android decides to kill your `activity1`, `someList` will be null. (This can happen if memory is low, eg. if your `activity2` uses a lot of memory.)

> Will the objects from a parent activity always stay in memory while the child activity is visible?

No, they may not stay in memory since android can kill your activity which is not visible at any time. (this does not usually happen though, since most devices have enough memory)

---

> ```
> /* The next activity has no parent and can be launched 
> *  when the app receives an intent, for example a 
> *  photo is shared to my app.
> */
> activityX{
>   ....
>   receive_intent(...);
>   do_something(activity1.someList) // This might work, when app is already running
> }
> ```

What if your user shares a photo without starting your app first? ...`SomeList` will be null. (it will generate a `NullPointerException` if your activity is not running in the background)

---

Don't rely on your app being running, since the android system may kill your app **at any time!**

If possible, you should transfer your data via intents or recreate as needed. If you want to transfer an array / list via intent, the `Intent` class provides [ways of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374546/passing-arraylist-through-intent). If you really need to transfer objects, you should use `Parcelable`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents?rq=1).

There is an interesting thread about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/I1swY6FlbPI).

And oh, memory leaks:
For example, if you have an inner class, and instantiate this into a static variable in your activity, you will get a memory leak, as the static variable will outlive the activity. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks) for a better explanation)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was just trying to safe memory and cpu by using objects that have already been created in a previous activity. But yeah, if the app *might* crash then, it's obviously not worth it.

Comment: @potAito It's generally not worth trying to save cpu / memory if your app may crash as a result. Also, you won't save that much memory anyway, since a list with 1000 items will only be a few hundred KB anyway. Also, it does not cost much cpu to create objects, and your app will (usually) be just as fast and smooth whatever you do. But if doing this works for you, and your app _does not_ crash, go ahead and do it !

Comment: @ JonasCz well I asked since I wanted to know the proper way of doing it, and now I do :)