# Why defining a static ImageView will cause memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

[image]

It says: Do not place android context classes in static fields, this is a memory leak.

I know that activity context should not be placed in static fields because it will be kept alive until the app process ends, and if it is passed to other classes using constructor, it will cause other classes to be kept alive as well.

But why `ImageView` cannot be static(I also found `SwipeRefreshLayout` cannot be static either)? Is it because ImageView contains a context? No warnings on defining other views like `Button`,`TextView` as static.

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Static Fields and Memory Leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks)

Comment: which java version are you using and IDE is eclipse?

Comment: @Minh Bui 1.8.0_60-b27, Android Studio