# Singleton usage in android single activity architecture

Tags: java, android, android-activity, singleton

I want to use my main activity as a singleton. My app has single activity architecture. I searched the internet and everyone tells don't use singleton main activity because it leaks memory but i don't understand the drawback if my app is single activity.

If someone can clarify this i would be super thankful.

I profiled my app before and after implementing singleton activity and results are same. Do you think is there a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : Static Fields and Memory Leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks)

Comment: @derpirscher i think it doesn't answer but thanks