# Getting Main Activity from Main Application

Tags: android-activity, android, android-context

I have the following manifest.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyMainApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also have the following global static function.

`MyMainApplication application = MyMainApplication.instance();`as technique described in [Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

I was wondering, out from `application` variable, is it possible for me to get `MyMainActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the application's main `Activity` using the `Application` instance.

Usually there is no reason to do this... perhaps there is a better solution than manipulating the main `Activity` directly as you apparently are doing. Maybe you should update your post explaining specifically what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score -3):

You can start the activity form the *MyMainApplication* class though it doesn't extends Activity
    In Main Application Class create new Intent and set the intent flags to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` . Activity gets instantiated. I have tested and verified.

code snippet for reference :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyMainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question... the OP asked how to get the main activity and you told him how to start it.