# Wrong size from Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()

Tags: android, image

I download image with this code:

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(source);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Android/data/com.my.pkg/"+url.getFile();
            File f=new File(path);
            if(!f.exists()) {
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

                f=new File(f.getParent());
                f.mkdirs();                 

                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int length;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                os.close();
                is.close();
            }
            drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        }
        return drawable;
    }
};
```

This image has size 20x20. But drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() and drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() return 27. And image looks larger. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BitmapDrawable must scale bitmap to compensate for different screen densities.

If you need it to draw pixel-for-pixel, try setting Drawable's source density & target density to same value. To do this, you need slightly different objects to work with.

Instead of

```
drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
```

use

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
bmp.setDensity(dm.densityDpi);
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp, context.getResources());
```

If you don't have context (which you should), you can use application context, see e.g. [Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

Since bitmap's density is set to resources' density, which is actual device's screen's density, it should draw without scaling.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, the API has changed and the last line should be:
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);

Answer (score 7):

I tried the code form the answer and did not work. So instead i used the code below and it worked fine.

```
     DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

     Options options=new Options();
     options.inDensity=dm.densityDpi;
     options.inScreenDensity=dm.densityDpi;
     options.inTargetDensity=dm.densityDpi;      

     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
     drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp, context.getResources());
```

Comment: Both solution worked for me, however, yours is closer to the new API changes. Thanks again.