# How get the context in a class which extends Exception

Tags: android, exception, android-context

I tried everything, this 
[Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)
and few things more and nothing works.

I need the application context in my DatabaseException class which extends Exception. 
I need it because I want to check some `sharedpreferences` when the exceptions are launched. 
The code basically is this:

```
public class DatabaseException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

DatabaseException(){
    super();
}

DatabaseException(String s){
    super(s);
}

public DatabaseException (String s, Throwable t){
    super (s,t);
    kindOfException(t.getCause(), s);
}

DatabaseException (Throwable t){
    super (t);
    kindOfException(t.getCause(), null);
}
```

...

```
private void createLog() {
    Log.d("Database Exception","On Create Log");
    String listLogs;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(DatabaseException.class.context);
```

of course this doesn't work. So... please, somebody can help me?

Comment: Add context field to your class and context param to the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Simply.. you can not. But when the `Execption` is raised you can perform

```
private void createLog() {
    this.getContext();
    Log.d("Database Exception","On Create Log");
    String listLogs;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(DatabaseException..
}
```

the operation you need in the `catch` clause.

You could pass it as paramter but, please, avoid it.

Comment: I will try it but, could you tell me why is better avoid pass the context as parameter?

Comment: It could cause of memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you, the others answers works and are more close what I wanted in the beginning but they are more like patchs than what it should be a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DatabaseException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public YourContext context;
public DatabaseException(YourContext context){
    this.context = context;
}
}
```

Now if you catch the exception:

```
try {
    ...
} (catch DatabaseException e) {
    MyContext context = e.context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
1. Add application context as parameter of the DatabaseException construtor. 
2. Put your DatabaseException as other class's inner class. (Other class means Activity...), so you can use fields/method of outer class in the inner class.
3. ...

Comment: It cannot be inner class of any other class.

Comment: Ok, method 2 doesn't work in your use case, then try method 1 as other's suggestion. :)