# Is the Android Context mutable?

Tags: android

I want to store the application context in a static member, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android), so I can access it, the shared preferences, resources etc. everywhere.

My question is whether the context can change itself during the application lifetime, so the stored context won't work in a proper way and I can't access shared preferences etc.

Or is the context immutable, so I can use it without any doubt?

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: It is fine to store the context in a static variable. Make sure you use getApplicationContext() to do it. This has nothing to do with whether it's mutable.

Comment: This sounds great for me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Application context stays unaltered during application lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Context is immutable during all work of app. And you can use it in static way to get resources, shared preferences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the accepted answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere), you will find that it is Ok to do this, but handle with care...

> There are a couple of potential problems with this approach, 
>   though in a lot of circumstances (such as your example) it will work well.
>
> In particular you should be careful when dealing with anything that deals with the GUI 
>   that requires a Context. For example, if you pass the application Context into the
>   LayoutInflator you will get an Exception. Generally speaking, your approach is excellent:
>   it's good practice to use an Activity's Context within that Activity, and the Application
>   Context when passing a context beyond the scope of an Activity to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use it with shared preferences and get resources etc.

getApplicationContext() function should do it. It shouldn't matter if its mutable.