# What is the Difference between using getApplicationcontext() & this in Toast .maketext() method

Tags: android, android-context

Is there any specific instance where i have to use getApplicationcontext() or this in the context parameter of Toast.makeText() method

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationcontext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141369/difference-between-getapplicationcontext-and-classname-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***getApplicationContext*** :

As per [Developer documention : getApplicationContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29)

`Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.`

Use:

`You can use throughout your application with the help of getting Application context using`

```
public class YourApp extends Application
{
 static YourApp appstate;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate();
    appstate = this;
   }
 public static YourApp getApplication(){
    return appstate;
   }
}
```

How to use it : `YourApp.getApplication();`

---

***this***

`Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object.`

Use: `You can use as along as you can see your Activity Context`

e.g.

```
public void onCreate(Bundled savedInstanceState)
{
 ...
Toast.makeText(this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

How one can differentiate use of `this` and `getApplicationContext()` using `Toast.makeText()`?

Try to use Toast.makeText() in `AynscTask` with `this` and `getApplicationContext`.

Comment: how do u become such an expert in android programming .i am difficult having trouble with understanding programs itself.any tip for a noob to become more like you

Answer (score 2):

You can follow

```
View.getContext(): Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity.

Activity.getApplicationContext(): Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity.
```

"this" and getContext() both are same

[Reference] [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and “this”][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and/10641257#10641257)