# android checkbox is doubled when i put a background

Tags: java, android, checkbox, drawable

I'm trying to set a custom background to a check box, but it's doubled, and i don't know why.

My Main activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    DrawableCheckButton d = new DrawableCheckButton(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    setContentView(cb);
}
```

DrawableCheckButton class :

```
public class DrawableCheckButton extends StateListDrawable {

public DrawableCheckButton(Context context) {
    int[] state_checked = { android.R.attr.state_checked };
    int[] state_active = { android.R.attr.state_enabled };
    CustomDrawableCheckButton d = new CustomDrawableCheckButton(context);
    CustomDrawableCheckButton2 d2 = new CustomDrawableCheckButton2(context);
    addState(state_checked, d);
    addState(state_active, d2);
}

}
```

And the other class look like this

```
public class CustomDrawableCheckButton extends Drawable{
private Context context;
public CustomDrawableCheckButton(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path1 = new Path();
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    path1.moveTo(0, 3);
    path1.lineTo(17, 3);
    path1.moveTo(0, 3);
    path1.lineTo(0, 23);
    path1.lineTo(20, 23);
    path1.lineTo(20, 14);
    paint1.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    //
    Path path2 = new Path();
    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    path2.moveTo(4,10);
    path2.lineTo(10, 16);
    path2.lineTo(22, 4);
    paint2.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
    paint2.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);

}
```

I need some help.

Comment: What do you mean by doubled ? Do you have a screenshot ?

Comment: because the checkbox is in the checkmark, not in the background, i'd say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was instead of doing cb.setBackgroundDrawable(), i just did cb.setButtonDrawable(). Background is for the all and button is for the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion: 
In `MainActivity`, you should avoid using `ApplicationContext`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere) for more information, and use `setButtonDrawable` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    DrawableCheckButton d = new DrawableCheckButton(this);
    cb.setButtonDrawable(d);
    setContentView(cb);
}
```

In `DrawableCheckButton`:

```
public DrawableCheckButton(Context context) {
    CustomDrawableCheckButton d = new CustomDrawableCheckButton(context);
    addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked }, d);
    CustomDrawableCheckButton2 d2 = new CustomDrawableCheckButton2(context);
    addState(new int[]{}, d2);
}
```

Hope that help. Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Sorry, i found the answer, it's much simplier. instead of doing cb.setBackgroundDrawable(), i just did cb.setButtonDrawable(). Background is for the all and button is for the mark.

Comment: sorry for previous answer, I have updated it for anyone who meets the same problem.