# Toast in Fragment not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toast

I have looked through multiple answers and tried their solutions, but I am still unable to get a toast to show in my application. I am working with a Fragment because my application has multiple tabs. Here is my code:

```
package edu.uah.smap.smapscanner.tabsswipe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment
{

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }

@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

In place of `getActivity()`, I have tried

- `getActivity().getActivityContext()`,
- `Tab1Fragment.this.getActivity()`, and
- `Tab1Fragment.this.getActivity().getActivityContext()`

None of those have worked.

Here is the MainTabs activity code:

```
package edu.uah.smap.smapscanner;

import edu.uah.smap.smapscanner.tabsswipe.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainTabs extends FragmentActivity 
          implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
private ViewPager        m_viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter m_adapter;
private ActionBar        m_actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Check-in/Check-out", "My Items", "Lab Inventory" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_main);

    // Initialization
    m_viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    m_actionBar = getActionBar();
    m_adapter   = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    m_viewPager.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    m_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {
            //on changing the page make the respected tab selected
            m_actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {

        }

        @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
        {

    }
    });

    m_actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    m_actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) 
    {
   m_actionBar.addTab(m_actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  } 

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    // on tab selected show respected fragment view
    m_viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{

}

}
```

Comment: what type of activity you used and also can you post your activity code

Comment: try simply this -> Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I've already tried the getActivity() alone, sorry I made a mistake in my question.

Comment: I don't know what activity I am using, where do I find that?

Comment: @setherj are you extending activity? or framentactivity?

Comment: The main class that sets up the tabs is extending FragmentActivity.

Comment: @setherj does it return you some error on the logcat, or simply doesn't show the `Toast`? Also, can you post the code for your activity?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

---

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987503/399459). There is a difference of when to use Activity context and when to use Application Context.

Use the **Application Context** when you leave the scope of the `Activity`. In certain cases you have to use the **Activity Context** or you will get exceptions, in others you should use the **Application Context** to avoid leaking the `Activity` context.

Answer (score 3):

you can use 
getApplicationContext()

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```