# Cannot call AsyncTask from a static method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask, static-methods

I can't seem to call a AsyncTask from a static method. It says "cannot be referenced from a static context". It is important that this method IS static and I need to have it like that for a few other processes of mine.

Is there a way to call the AsyncTask from the method?

```
public static void UpdateResults(String requestSearch){
    new GetSearchResults(requestSearch).execute(); //shows an error
}

class GetSearchResults extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String requestSearch;

    GetSearchResults(String searchtext){
        this.requestSearch = searchtext;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //functions continuing 
    }
}
```

EDIT: Anands solution worked however it threw this exception as soon as it got to the method:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.eproject.eproject.emobile, PID: 26831
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.eproject.eproject.emobile.SearchTabs.SearchPeopleTab$GetSearchResults.doInBackground(SearchPeopleTab.java:78)
            at com.eproject.eproject.emobile.SearchTabs.SearchPeopleTab$GetSearchResults.doInBackground(SearchPeopleTab.java:63)
```

The line 78 which shows null pointer, points to this line of code:

```
SharedPreferences accPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "accPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Looks like it can't get hold of the SharedPreferences from the AsyncTask method now. It worked well before. What is wrong with it?

Comment: then try to call directly asynch

Comment: @user3676184 What do you mean mate?

Comment: call new GetSearchResults(requestSearch).execute(); this when you need to call asynch. why you create separate method for it

Comment: As in, take the asynctask stuff inside the static void UpdateResults method? @user3676184

Comment: ok. But you can do all stuff in GetSearchResults also.

Comment: @Earthling in which class this method `UpdateResults` belong?

Comment: ok. But you can do all stuff in GetSearchResults also.

Comment: Same class @AnandSingh

Comment: i want name of that class @Earthling

Comment: SearchPeopleTab @AnandSingh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Async` class is a `non-static` inner class inside of your `Activity`, then you need an `instance` of the enclosing class in order to `instantiate` the `inner class`.

You have to call like this way inside `static` method:

```
SearchPeopleTab outerClass = new SearchPeopleTab(); //Outer class
        GetSearchResults task = outerClass.new GetSearchResults(requestSearch);
        task.execute();
```

Comment: some value is `null` in your doInBackground method. Can you post code of your do in background? (Line 78) @Earthling

Comment: Although this answers the question, the code is very unconventional.

Comment: What's the conventional way to do it @Hindol? I'm open for more ideas

Comment: I have one idea, but it may not be the best. Since you need access to context (*Activity* **is** *Context*) from a static method, you can use the Application Context. See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere). Then you need not access the *outer class* from the *inner class*, which is a bad practice IMO. You cannot then move the inner class to a separate file easily.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your inner class as `static`:

```
static class GetSearchResults extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

Or move it into its own file.

Comment: I don't know why you got the downvote but this almost does the trick. It's just that the application's context cannot be referenced from a static method now. For example: SharedPreferences accpref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "accpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: In terms of your posted code, this answer is correct. If you are trying to reference member variables or methods of the outer class in the inner class (not shown in question), you have a problem: you need an instance of the outer class. Impossible to say how to make this change without more information.

Comment: Quite simply, I'm trying to get the application context inside the GetSearchResults AsyncTask but since I changed it to static, it won't let me refer the getActivity() context now, mate

Comment: If you want to call an instance method on a class, you need an instance of the class. You don't have this in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

your method UpdateResults is static,but inner class  GetSearchResults is not defined static,you can not involve none static class in static method,because none class is belong to object,but in static method there is no ogject