# Localizing SQL in Android

Tags: android, database, localization, resources

I'm preparing database definition class for my application. Let me abbreviate it a little:

```
public class DatabaseDefinition {

     public static class Table {

         public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MyTable";

         public static final int ID_FIELD = "ID";
         public static final String DATA_FIELD = "Data";

         public static final String CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
             ID_FIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
             DATA_FIELD + " TEXT)";

         public static String getCreateSql() {

             return CREATE_SQL;
         }
     }
}
```

I'd like to add some data to this table when the database is being created (very few, like max. 10 entries). The problem is, that this data must be localized. I may store appropriate entries in resources, but I'm not aware of any way of accessing resources without context and I have none in `onCreate` event of my `DatabaseHelper`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {

    database.execSQL(DatabaseDefinition.GetCreateSql());
}
```

How can I access resources from here? Or how else should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Context.getApplicationContext()` or implement own class extending `Application`, as described here: [Using Application context everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)