# Save Android App's ApplicationContext when Application.onCreate()

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

As the title indicated, I have a doubt that can I save the Application instance(certainly a singleton) as a static field when Application.onCreate() is invoked as the app start, thus I could get the application context anywhere in all of my code even if I don't have a activity, fragment, view or anything else.

That seems to be fantastic but I'm also afraid is there any risks?

Comment: Yes there are potential problems. like inflating layout [Link to similar ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere)

Comment: I've browsed that question before ask I also did a demo and found out there is something wrong to do with ApplicationContext used for GUI about. However what I interest in most is to deal with something like SharedPreference with this context, I cannot find a certain YES/NO answer in that question and somewhere else. You know, sometimes a math class also need saved config parameters and it seems to be not elegante to pass a activity context to the math class. @SouravGanguly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the help from `Application` class,

Read this > https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

> Base class for maintaining global application state. You can provide
>   your own implementation by creating a subclass and specifying the
>   fully-qualified name of this subclass as the "android:name" attribute
>   in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag. The Application
>   class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated
>   before any other class when the process for your application/package
>   is created.
>
> Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most
>   situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a
>   more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for
>   example to register broadcast receivers), include
>   Context.getApplicationContext() as a Context argument when invoking
>   your singleton's getInstance() method.

You can do that by keeping a Base class to maintain global application state,here in my example useed the Application object as a singleton object

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication singleton;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```

In your `AndroidManifest` specify that using `android:name` under application tag

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyApplication">
```

Now you can access this anywhere like

```
MyApplication mApplication = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: But since getApplicationContext() is a method of Context and there's a some limitation, will it be OK if I read some config parameters which are saved in SharedPreference via the ApplicationContext gotten by MyApplication.getSingleton.getApplicationContext() ?