# Android Toast Message is not showing in different aplications

Tags: java, android-studio, toast

I do not know why, but my toast not showing in applications. Only working in my application, but not in other applications for example in Messages. On my phone, I have Android 7.0.

```
case 53:
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
```

Comment: Are you sure your code actually gets to `case 53:`?

Comment: Yea, I have Honor 8 and not working. I tried on phone my collegue Samsung Galaxy S8 and Toast working. So I do not know where is the problem?

Comment: I did it and nowwhere errors. Maybe emui is the problem?

Comment: Please Read the first answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere

Comment: U mean to use this "getApplicationContext()" I tried it before and still not working.

Comment: Does Toast work on that phone in any app? And does it work if you try it from other parts of your app?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `getActivityContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Tried, but error. Cannot resolve method "getActivityContext()".