# Is the Context returned from Application the same as getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, android-context

The following is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987072/4070848) with one added function `getAppContext()`:

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {

    private static MyApp instance;

    public MyApp() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

But is there any difference between the context returned by `getContext()` and `getAppContext()`?  And is it the same context that is returned by `getApplicationContext()` within an `Activity` or elsewhere?  Are they all what is referred to as the "application context"?

Comment: You can try it yourself. From inside an Activity lifecycle call `System.out.format("Context equals? %s", getApplicationContext().equals(MyApp.getContext())).flush();`

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {
 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    instance = this

}

  companion object {
        var instance: MyApp? = null
  }
```

class MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val isSame = TheApplication.instance == applicationContext
        Log.e(
            TAG,
            "onCreate: $isSame, " +
                "TheApplication.instance: ${TheApplication.instance}, " +
                "applicationContext: ${applicationContext}"
        )
    }

}
```

Result :

```
MainActivity: onCreate: true, 
TheApplication.instance: com.example.MyApp@6a56b6, 
applicationContext: com.example.MyApp@6a56b6
```

Yes, they are the same objects.