# Is the Application context always available?

Tags: android, android-context

The following is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987072/4070848):

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {

    private static MyApp instance;

    public MyApp() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

But is the context returned by `MyApp.getContext()` always available?  For example, if I call it after a long-running operation... can task killers and other system power saving features kill the application (and its context) completely in the meantime, or will I always have a context to work with by calling `MyApp.getContext()`?

Answer (score 1):

init instance in onCreate, not in constructor. Do this:

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {
 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    instance = this

}

  companion object {
        var instance: MyApp? = null
  }
```

Comment: What difference does it make putting it in onCreate()?  And what is the answer to the question?